# How strong you can brew a beer using Brubox kit?

Tags: first-time-brewer, kits, alcohol-content

There is a [BrüBox](http://www.brubox.co/) which allows you to brew your own craft beer at home.

What's the estimated alcohol percentage you can achieve by using the provided equipment and following the instructions from the BrüBox brewing kit?

Answer (score 4):

Beer kits generally end up somewhere near or just below the 5% ABV mark. It is easy to add sugar/glucose to the wort to make it a higher ABV. Generally using added sugars one can get to somewhere around 10% ABV or so. Beer is rarely made less than 3% ABV even for a "session beer kit".

Answer (score 2):

I agree with barking.pete

They don't mention anything on their website except that you can choose from Porter, Session IPA or Weissbier.  Based on my experience with Cooper's Kit, they usually are just below 5%.   However, my local brew store make their own kits that are between 4.5% and 8% depending on the type of beer, so it is a possiblility.

You can always increase alcohol by adding sugar or add some malt (since it seems to be an all grain kit, requiring a mash).